# Preg Replace Remove Trailing Space on Output

Tags: php, regex

I am using preg_replace to generate contextual links in text blocks using the following code:

```
$contextualLinkStr = 'mytext';

$content = 'My text string which includes MYTEXT in various cases such as Mytext and mytext. However it also includes image tags such as <img src="http://www.myurl.com/mytext-1.jpg">';

$content = preg_replace('/' . $contextualLinkStr . '/i ', '<a href="foo.html">\\0</a>', $content);
```

I have a trailing space in my preg_replace in my search pattern. This is because I want the function to ignore any instances of mytext that appear in image links. This works but causes a problem with the output. The output also carries the trailing space as follows:

```
<a href="foo.html">mytext </a>
```

So my question is - How do I remove the trailing space from within the link on the output and then add a trailing space after the link to account for the already removed space. I need the output to be as follows:

```
<a href="foo.html">mytext</a>_
```

Where "_" is the trailing space. Can anybody please help?

Thanks,

Jason.

Comment: i didn't experience any space after mytext.

Comment: You can do this using word boundaries `\b` and `Negative Lookahead`, see [example](https://eval.in/165522)

Comment: To ignore image links, you are replaceing `mytext ` with a space, right? So is there a typo on your first line or in the replace function? I don't see where the space comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To ignore image links, use (*SKIP)(*F)**

To ignore `mytext` in image links, don't introduce a space when you are matching. Instead, use this regex to ignore image links direcly:

```
(?i)<img[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|mytext
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL1aG0).

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `<img links>` then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches `mytext`, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

Using this, you can do a straight preg_replace:

```
$regex = "~(?i)<img[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|" . $contextualLinkStr . "~";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,'<a href="foo.html">$0</a>',$content);
```

For full details on this exclusion technique and its many applications, see the question and article in the reference.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: That's perfect. Much better than my hacked attempt. Thanks!